# How do I install X4R package on R?

Tags: r, installation, cube

I am trying to install X4R package to load a cube in R. There is a package with limited support to do this called 'X4R'. It can be found here:
https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=77616&type=member&item=265568694&commentID=-1&trk=groups_guest_item_detail-b-jump_last#lastComment

and 
https://github.com/overcoil/X4R

I have tried:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
install.packages("Rcpp", lib="C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")
install_github("overcoil/X4R")
```

Since I am in a VM with no internet access, I used this line instead of last line in the above syntax:

```
install.packages("//tsclient/D/user1/R packages/X4R-master.zip",  repos =NULL,lib="C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")
```

There is no error message displayed, but library didn't get installed.

So I tried this step:
`install_local("//tsclient/D/user1/R packages/X4R-master.zip")`

The above step produces same error posted in LinkedIn page:

g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I.   -I"C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c soapXmlaWebServiceSoapProxy.cpp -o soapXmlaWebServiceSoapProxy
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I.   -I"C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c stdsoap2.cpp -o stdsoap2.o
stdsoap2.cpp:75:0: warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
stdsoap2.cpp:77:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
stdsoap2.cpp: In function 'const char* soap_strerror(soap*)':
stdsoap2.cpp:16229:11: warning: variable 'len' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o X4R.dll tmp.def X4R.o soapC.o soapXmlaWebServiceSoapProxy.o stdsoap2.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/library/Rcpp/libs/i386 -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/library/Rcpp/libs/x64 -lRcpp -lws2_32 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lRcpp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'X4R'
* removing 'C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/X4R'
Error: Command failed (1)

This is my sessionInfo().

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1](https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=77616&type=member&item=265568694&commentID=-1&trk=groups_guest_item_detail-b-jump_last#lastComment) LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=77616&type=member&item=265568694&commentID=-1&trk=groups_guest_item_detail-b-jump_last#lastComment) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=77616&type=member&item=265568694&commentID=-1&trk=groups_guest_item_detail-b-jump_last#lastComment) devtools_1.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=77616&type=member&item=265568694&commentID=-1&trk=groups_guest_item_detail-b-jump_last#lastComment) tools_3.1.0

Looks like there are people successfully using this package. I would appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to add the R output:

Comment: It seems that Rcpp cannot be found. Try installing that package and try again.

Comment: How can I specify the folder where Rcpp need to be installed? I have tried both library locations. Rcpp installs correctly, but no X4R.

Comment: I think I figured it out. @Paul, Thank you for suggesting what could be wrong in this situation. I copied the Rcpp library folder into all the folders that were used for libraries. i.e., I used `.libPaths()` to find the library folders, and copied Rcpp into all those folders.

Comment: Good to hear. Please feel free to answer your own question, than others can also benefit.